# Spring Constructor with 2 arguments where one need to be injected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to create an instance of a `RestTemplate` inside the constructor of a class using the `RestTemplateBuilder`. I would like to autowire the `RestTemplateBuilder` in the constructor and pass another parameter "manually". Is this possible?

My approach so far:

```
public class IlikeU {

    private final String blub;
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

        public IlikeU(final String blub, @Autowired final RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
            this.blub = blub;
            this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
        }
    }
```

I want to create an instance like the following but cant because the constructor expects 2 params.

```
IlikeU iLikeU = new IlikeU("pew pew");
```

Comment: Firstly are you going to be injecting the `ILikeU` class as a dependency somewhere or are you just going to be instantiating it yourself?

Comment: So far Im instantiating it by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work like that - you either pass object creation to Spring, or handle it yourself. Spring is not a pre-processor that will expose you a different interface - it will use your interface to handle it automatically.

What you can do, is to also provide `bluc` value to the Spring context and automate it completely:

```
public IlikeU(@Value("${your.parameter}") final String blub, @Autowired final RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder)
```

You need to define your value as a key `your.parameter` in the properties available to your context.

Other possibility is to build a factory, that will get a rest template builder from Spring and build your `IlikeU` class with given string:

```
public class IlikeUFactory {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public IlikeUFactory(@Autowired final RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }

    public IlikeU createIlikeU(String blub) {
        return new IlikeU(blub, this.restTemplate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do exactly like that. How about alternative way, like in following code?

```
@Component
public class IUseU{
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

    public void use(){
        IlikeU iLikeU = new IlikeU("pew pew", restTemplateBuilder);
    }
}

public class IlikeU {

    private final String blub;
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public IlikeU(final String blub, final RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        this.blub = blub;
        this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

> Side Note: The advantage of spring framework is dependency injection.
>   So if you are using spring, you should not use `new XXXX()` in your
>   code and let spring framework handle that part for you.
>
> By doing that, you get advantage of loose coupling. You can replace
>   that class with different one later. Otherwise, over long run, you will find yourself 
>   very difficult to replace any class.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to FranXho's answer you can also use @Required 
With autowired if you don't want to loose advantage of constructor dependencey.